# Using a non-query expression to flatten a List of one type to another

Tags: c#-4.0

Is it possible to use a non-query expression to flatten a list of one type into a list of another type?

```
public class TypeQuote
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
}

public class BidAskQuote
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public decimal bidPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal askPrice { get; set; }

}

List<TypeQuote> quotes = new List<TypeQuote>();

quotes[0] = new TypeQuote() { symbol = "IBM", type = "Bid", price = 167.24M };
quotes[1] = new TypeQuote() { symbol = "IBM", type = "Ask", price = 167.35M };
quotes[2] = new TypeQuote() { symbol = "MSFT", type = "Bid", price = 63.46M };
quotes[3] = new TypeQuote() { symbol = "MSFT", type = "Ask", price = 63.52M };

List<BidAskQuote> bidAskQuotes = 
quotes.GroupBy(g => g.symbol, new BidAskQuote { symbol = g.symbol, ??? }).ToList();
```

I'm stuck on figuring out how to selectively assign the bidPrice and askPrice fields in the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further filter the group like:

```
List<TypeQuote> quotes = new List<TypeQuote>();

    quotes.Add(new TypeQuote() { symbol = "IBM", type = "Bid", price = 167.24M });
    quotes.Add(new TypeQuote() { symbol = "IBM", type = "Ask", price = 167.35M });
    quotes.Add(new TypeQuote() { symbol = "MSFT", type = "Bid", price = 63.46M });
    quotes.Add(new TypeQuote() { symbol = "MSFT", type = "Ask", price = 63.52M });

    var bidAskQuotes = quotes
        .GroupBy(g => g.symbol)
        .Select(grp => new BidAskQuote 
            {   
                symbol = grp.Key, 
                askPrice = grp.Where(x => x.type == "Ask").Select(x => x.price).FirstOrDefault(),
                bidPrice = grp.Where(x => x.type == "Bid").Select(x => x.price).FirstOrDefault()
            });
```